# getting data after async functions executed in an old ES version

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following code with two functions that get executed asynchronously

```
products = [];
categories = [];
getProduct = function() {
    productService.list().then(function(result) {
        products = ["product1", "product2"]
    });
}

getcategories = function() {
    categoryService.list().then(function(result) {
        categories = ["category1", "category2"]
    });
}
```

i want another function that accept the two parameters, products and categories, something like that:

```
all = function(products, categories) {
    console.log(products, categories);
}
```

but of course because of the async function, i'll get undefined. is there anyway to get the data after the previous functions get executed. m using old javascript so i can't use asynch await .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promises chaining, call one by one,
see:

```
products = [];
categories = [];

productService.list()
     .then(function(result) {
        products = ["product1", "product2"]; // products = result;
        return categoryService.list();
     }).then(function(result) {
        categories = ["category1", "category2"]; // categories = result;
        all(products, categories);
     }).catch(function(ex) {
        // Error handele
     }) ;
```

see exmple [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

one more option is to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
it can fit your use case as you don't need to read the functions one by one. in this option you should do something like:

```
Promise.all([productService.list(), categoryService.list()]).then(function(values) {
  all(value[0],value[1]);
});
```

Comment: Like for the "mini" code. As I did not notice that the methods ".list()" were returning a Promise, but can even be more improved, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

**ES6 Solution with `Promise.all`:**

**EDIT For shortest solution**:

```
Promise.all([productService.list(), categoryService.list()]).then(values => all(...values));
```

**Previous Solution:**

```
getProduct = function() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        productService.list().then(function(result) {
            res(["product1", "product2"]);
        });
    });
}

getcategories = function() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        categoryService.list().then(function(result) {
            res(["category1", "category2"]);
        });
    });
}

Promise.all([getProduct(), getcategories()]).then(aResolveValues => {
    aResolveValues[0] //Has the values of the first resolve promise (products)
    aResolveValues[1] //Has the values of the second resolve promise (categories)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain if your situation suits it, or depending on your version of js (you don't mention what version you're targeting) you can either use `Promise.all` or fallback to a basic callback, e.g:

```
var products, categories,
all = function () {
  if (products && categories) {
    console.log(products, categories);
  }
},
getProducts = function (oncomplete) {
  return productService.list().then(function(result) {
    products = ["product1", "product2"];
    oncomplete();
  });
},
getCategories = function (oncomplete) {
  return categoryService.list().then(function(result) {
    categories = ["category1", "category2"];
    oncomplete();
  });
};
getProducts(all) && getCategories(all);
```